# Did i invoke the objects wrong, there are 2 null keys in one map using Karate API

Tags: karate

- def array = [Red,Green,Yellow,null]
- def map = {'Red': 0, 'Green': 0, 'Yellow': 0 , 'Grey': 0, null : 0}
- karate.forEach(array, function(x){ map.put(x,map.get(x) + 1) })
- print map

Output :
{
"Red": 1,
"Green": 1,
"Yellow": 1,
"Grey": 0,
"null": 0,
"null": 1.0
}

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why the 2 nulls show up. Feel free to debug and let us know, this is never a concern in normal use, you should never have null keys anyway when all the code behind expects strings. Make this one change please:

```
* karate.forEach(array, function(x){ if (x) map[x] = map.get(x) + 1 })
```

Comment: The Use case is from a nested json, i get bunch of values along with null (Object, Not String) i tried playing around but still i see 2 keys, this workaround works for me now (making null as string ).
* def array = ["Red","Green","Yellow",null]
    * def map = {'Red': 0, 'Green': 0, 'Yellow': 0 , 'Grey': 0, 'null' : 0}
    * karate.forEach(array, function(x){ map.put(x,map.get(x) + 1) })
    * print map
    * print map.get(null)
    * print map.get('null')
Outcome for this is : [print]{  "Red": 1,  "Green": 1,  "Yellow": 1,  "Grey": 0,  "null": 0,  "null": 1.0}
[print] 1.0
[print] 0